# difference between $(*[attr]) and $([attr])

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to know which one is preferable in the following `$(*[attr])` and `$([attr])`. Why?

Because both are doing same.

```js
$('[onclick]').each(function(i,elem){
  console.log(elem.onclick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="asd()"></div>
<div onclick="def()"></div>
<div id="dv1"></div>
<div id="dv2"></div>
```

```js
$('*[onclick]').each(function(i,elem){
  console.log(elem.onclick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="asd()"></div>
<div onclick="def()"></div>
<div id="dv1"></div>
<div id="dv2"></div>
```

And also what about the browser support.

Apologize if i asked the duplicate one.

Comment: I would surely prefer `$('[onclick]')` as `*` doesn't make any sense here, since the objective is to select all element with said attribute

Comment: @Satpal any performance or browser support difference between them?

Comment: better create a test case at jspref

Comment: @Satpal i tried in jspref here i posted that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Both are same in behavioral level.

As @satpal said in comment.

I tried in jsPref, It says `$('*[onclick]')` is the fastest.

[image]

Thanks @satpal

Comment: @RolandStarke i takes 0.0004521 seconds if you want, you can verify